# Need to know the origin and coordinates for 2d texture and 2d/3d vertices in webgl

Tags: textures, coordinates, vertex, webgl

**Long story short, I know my coordinates are off and I believe my indices might be off.**

I'm trying to render a simple 2d rectangle with a texture in webgl

here's the code I have for the vbo/ibo:

```
rectVertices.vertices = new Float32Array(
[
    -0.5, -0.5,  // Vertice 1, bottom /  left
     0.0,  0.0,  // UV 1

    -0.5,  0.5,  // Vertice 2,    top /  left
     0.0,  1.0,  // UV 2

     0.5,  0.5,  // Vertice 3,    top / right
     1.0,  1.0,  // UV 3

     0.5, -0.5,  // Vertice 4, bottom / right
     1.0,  0.0,  // UV 4
]);

rectVertices.indices = new Int16Array([
    0,1,2,2,0,3
]);


/* I'm assuming the vertices go like this

(-0.5, 0.5) ------ ( 0.5, 0.5)
            |    |
            |    |
(-0.5,-0.5) ------ ( 0.5,-0.5)

with the origin in the middle

and the texture coordinates go like this:

( 0.0, 1.0) ------ ( 1.0, 1.0)
            |    |
            |    |
( 0.0, 0.0) ------ ( 1.0, 0.0)

so as you can see I'm all messed up.

I'm also using:

gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

*/
```

Here's the output of the program:

[image]

the texture I'm using is this:

[image]

**So, I guess I need to know the origins, but the triangle strip looks way off.**

I am doing this as well:

```
// create VBO and IBO    
vbo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertices.vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

ibo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertices.indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

and:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexAttribute ,2, gl.FLOAT, false,FLOAT*2,FLOAT*0); // position
gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureAttribute,2, gl.FLOAT ,false,FLOAT*2,FLOAT*2); // texture
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttribute);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(textureAttribute);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

**It almost seems as though the Vertices and the UV coordinates are getting mixed up.**

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start your indices from 0 so it should become:

```
rectVertices.indices = new Int16Array([ 0,1,2,0,2,3  ]);
```

[Edit]

It seems you are using triangle strip rather than triangles. The indices you are using are for triangles, which I think is the usual thing to do unless you have some performance issues. Don't use triangle strips as they are meant to be some kind of mesh *compression*.

So you need to change the draw call from GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP to GL_TRIANGLES.

In case you need to use triangles strips check how they should be connected [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip).

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm getting a funky picture, let me edit my post and you can take a look.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @mathacka did that solve the problem ?

Comment: no, I think I'm reading the vertices wrong, I was able to get it working when I put all the vertices in front, with the texture coordinates after, I don't know what I'm doing wrong to interleave them

Comment: well, I dont know everything about your code but these indices [0,1,2,0,2,3] are clearly intended for triangles draw call and not triange strips. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip

Answer (score 0):

I think you can think of indices as how the vertices in order of as drawing goes. I got stuck on that for a bit because that lost me for a while. If you can imagine taking out a piece of paper, imagine the dots as vertices and drawing a rectangle without lifting up the pencil back to it's original vertex. You've just encountered how indices draw to the graphics card.

Example would be this:

```
Vertex 01: -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
VERTEX 2: 1.0f 1.0f, 0.0f;
vertex 3: -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f;
vertex 4: 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f;

Indices : 0,1,2,3
```

If you have graph paper or something similar this could help a lot. So you can easily see the indices were drawn from the vertice 0 all the way to the vertex 4.